# Am I being Hacked? GalliumOS + Chromium

Tags: security, authentication, chromium, chromebook

I am using GalliumOS (Ubuntu 16.04 derivative) and Chromium Browser.

In the last week I have been informed by two major websites, Amazon and Coinbase, that the computer I have been using for the last two years is a "new device" and must be confirmed.

In both instances reconfirming the device via email solved the problem and I kind of forgot about it.

Then just now, whilst using Coinbase I was logged out because of an auth token error. I then had to log back in. 2 stage auth token is working fine.

Is someone trying to hack me or perhaps one of the two above mentioned sites? (I am sure someone somewhere is trying to hack them both ALL THE TIME... is someone getting close????)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen can you direct me where to repost and I will delete it myself. Never had to ask a Question of this sort and I'm a bit lost :/ thanks :)

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Questions about Gallium OS are off topic at Ask Ubuntu even though it's an Ubuntu derivative and instead should be asked at [Unix & Linux Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Maybe you could ask a moderator to migrate it there (by clicking the flag link under the question) because you already are a user at Unix & Linux Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably fine. The new device is likely be your computer getting a new IP and the auth error token could be any number of things, most of which aren't bad. If you are feeling paranoid, you can always change your passwords and enable 2FA.